# LNK1120 when building Python package referencing Boost

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I'm attempting to integrate Python into my C++ program using Boost.Python. I've been able to compile some modules just fine, but this one consistently gives me linker errors complaining about unresolved externals from `boost-system`.

I have the following module:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(platform)
{
    boost::python::class_<mandala::platform_win32_t, boost::noncopyable>("platform", boost::python::no_init)
        .def("get_window_title", &mandala::platform_win32_t::get_window_title);
}
```

And the following `setup.py` script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

setup(name='mandala',
    ext_modules=[
        Extension('platform',
            ['../mandala/platform_win32.cpp'],
        include_dirs=['C:\\boost_1_55_0',
        '..\ext\glm-0.9.4.4',
        '..\ext\glew-1.10.0\include',
        '..\ext\glfw-3.0.1.bin.WIN32\include'],
        library_dirs=['C:\\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib',
        '..\ext\glfw-3.0.1.bin.WIN32\lib-msvc110',
        '..\ext\glew-1.10.0\lib\Release\Win32'],
        libraries=['glfw3', 'glew32', 'opengl32', 'user32', 'gdi32']
        )
    ])
```

Wheen running it, I get the following output.

```
running build
running build_ext
building 'platform' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\boost_1_55_0 -I..\ext\glm-0.9.4.4 -I..\ext\glew-1.10.0\include -I..\ext\glfw-3.0.1.bin.WIN32\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tp../mandala/platform_win32.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\../mandala/platform_win32.obj
platform_win32.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\xlocale(337) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
c:\python27\include\pymath.h(22) : warning C4273: 'round' : inconsistent dll linkage
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\math.h(516) : see previous definition of 'round'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib /LIBPATH:..\ext\glfw-3.0.1.bin.WIN32\lib-msvc110 /LIBPATH:..\ext\glew-1.10.0\lib\Release\Win32 /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\PCbuild glfw3.lib glew32.lib opengl32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib /EXPORT:initplatform build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\../mandala/platform_win32.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-2.7\platform.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\../mandala\platform.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\../mandala\platform.pyd.manifest
   Creating library build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\../mandala\platform.lib and object build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\../mandala\platform.exp
platform_win32.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::throw_exception(class std::exception const &)" (?throw_exception@boost@@YAXABVexception@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::detail::shared_count::shared_count<void *,struct boost::python::converter::shared_ptr_deleter>(void *,struct boost::python::converter::shared_ptr_deleter)" (??$?0PAXUshared_ptr_deleter@converter@python@boost@@@shared_count@detail@boost@@QAE@PAXUshared_ptr_deleter@converter@python@2@@Z)
build\lib.win32-2.7\platform.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I have tried to put various `boost-system` libraries in the `libraries` array in the `setup.py` script, but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**
Entirety of `platform_win32.cpp` is [here](http://pastebin.com/38vYULcQ).

Comment: Could you provide signature of `mandala::platform_win32_t::get_window_title` function?

Comment: @kvorobiev `platform_t::window_title_type platform_win32_t::get_window_title() const
 {
  //TODO: implement this
  return std::string();
 }` :P

Comment: Hmm.. And could you add to your question entire `platform_win32_t` code?

Comment: @kvorobiev http://pastebin.com/38vYULcQ

Comment: It doesn't seem to have anything to do with that class in particular, I did the same thing with another class and got the exact same linker error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile error was fixed by adding `extra_compile_args=['/EHsc']` to the `setup.py` script.